# purevolume round corners

Tags: rounded-corners

does anyone know how purevolume.com gets their rounded corners? its very interesting and cross browser except I couldnt find the source code for it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of their background image:

https://www.purevolume.com/_images_new/header_nav_bg.png
[image]

This is, of course, one of many ways to accomplish this. In Chrome and Firefox you can use CSS:

```
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
```

Of course this won't work for Internet Explorer. For IE you would have to use a different technique - there are many. Doing the rounded corners in your background image is safe, but locks you into a box to where you have to edit images in order to change the visual shape of an element (not that bad, but not always encouraged).